# Powershell - How do I Prevent Newly Created Folder from adding my Username to the Permissions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm executing this piece of code as part of a new-aduser script:

```
$UN = "zoomz"
$RDSHF = "\\Alpha3\User1\Z\"+$UN

New-Item $RDSHF -ItemType directory

    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $RDSHF
    $Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("$UN","FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
    Set-Acl -Path $RDSHF $Acl
```

Which for all intended purposes is working as expected but on closer inspection when I manually check the permissions on the security tab of new folder its adding me with special permissions.

[Permission Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdYmF.png)

Is there a way to prevent the inclusion of my account when creating a new folder or can it be removed after the folder has been created bearing in mind that the user who runs the script and generates the new folder can be one of a dozen people.

****** UPDATE ******

I eventually got it sorted to my liking.

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "takeown /S ($FileServer) /A /R /F $RDSHF" -verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $RDSHF
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("$Env:USERNAME","FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($Ar)
Set-Acl -Path $RDSHF -AclObject $Acl
```

I ended up using takeown as an Administrator and then waited 2 seconds and applied $ACL.RemoveAccessRulleAll($Ar) in combination with $Env:USERNAME to remove my name from the folder.

So the end result is that "Administrators" is the owner of the group, the new user has full access to top level and sub-level folders and my name is removed too.

Comment: you can get the user that is executing the script through '$env:username', the domain if needed through '$env:userdomain'. Then you can remove the user from the ACL after creating the folder

Comment: Change owner of created folder from you to someone's else account, like target user, SYSTEM account or Administrators group.

Comment: Sorry, feel like i'm letting the team down here. I've researched further into ACLs and found that the  $Acl.SetOwner($Ar) command requires elevated rights.  I don't want the user to have to right-click and "run as administrator "  and when I try to pre-load the script with admin privledges it breaks the script altogether.  Short of running this portion of the script independently (which works) or running "takeown" from an elevated command prompt I'm really struggling to get this part of my script to execute.  

Is there anyway to run a single section of PowerShell code with elevated rights?

Comment: Thanks @Paul and (PetSerAI) for pointing me in the right direction